# I want a batch file to delete all files in an absolute path location (F:\work) except two files named "txt1.txt" and "txt2.txt"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, forfiles

I am using a cmd batch code to delete all files inside `F:\Work` folder except a file `txt1.txt`, the folder contains two files `txt1.txt` and `txt2.txt`.

This is the batch code I am using:

```
forfiles /p "f:\Work" /s /m *.*  /C "cmd /c if not @file==txt1.txt del @path"
```

It is deleting both `txt1.txt` and `txt2.txt`. What is wrong?

Comment: This site does not provide a code to request service, and as you are not new to this site, I ask that you revisit the [tour], and read through all of the pages of [ask], before you [edit] your question to be on topic according to that guidance. I also urge you to use the excellent search facility at the top of the page in order to locate similar questions and answers to assist you in creating a [mcve] of your intended code. If you want to use `forfiles`, open a Command Prompt window, type `forfiles /?` and read its usage information, then use that to help you to adapt the answers you found.

Comment: If you run your code with `echo on`, you'll notice that `@file` is quoted. So you have to compare `if not @file == "txt1.txt"`. But what's with `txt2.txt`?: `if not @file == "txt1.txt" if not @file == "txt2.txt" del @path`

Comment: Tried it stephan, still deleting both files

Comment: i found the solution, if not @file == """txt1.txt""", i should write 3 """ to work, dont know why

Comment: Not understanding why you are using `FORFILES` for this task?  A standard `FOR` command would be just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use [`forfiles`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) for your task, a standard [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) is perfectly suitable:

```cmd
for /R "F:\Work" %%I in (*) do if /I not "%%~nxI"=="txt1.txt" del "%%~I"
```

---

However, if you insist on using `forfiles`, then:

1. Do not specify mask `/M *.*` but use `/M *` instead (which is anyway the default), because the former skips files with no extension.
2. Regard that `forfiles` iterates over both files and directories, so use `/C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE …"` to process files only.
3. Escape quotes inside of `forfiles`' `/C` string, like `\"` or `0x22`. (I prefer the latter since the `"` in `\"` is still recognised by the command processor, which might require additional `^`-escaping in some situations, potentially leading to quite complicated and illegible escape sequences.)
4. Note that all file-name-related `@`-variables return quoted values, so `if [not] @file==txt1.txt` will never [not] match, but `if [not] @file==\"txt1.txt\"` will [not], and `if /I [not] @file==\"txt1.txt\"` will even ignore the case (as said escape `"` like `\"`).

Hence the correct command line is:

```cmd
forfiles /S /P "F:\Work" /M * /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE if /I not @file==\"txt1.txt\" del @path"
```

Or, with alternative quote escaping and skipped mask:

```cmd
forfiles /S /P "F:\Work" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE if /I not @file==0x22txt1.txt0x22 del @path"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy enough with PowerShell. PowerShell can run on all supported Windows systems. When you are satisfied that the correct files will be deleted, remove the `WhatIf` switch.

```
Remove-Item -Path 'F:\work\*' -Recurse -Exclude txt1.txt,txt2.txt -WhatIf
```

If you must run from a cmd.exe shell or in a .bat file script,

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Remove-Item -Path 'F:\work\*' -Recurse -Exclude txt1.txt,txt2.txt" -WhatIf
```